# why does `airflow connections list` shows unencrypted results?

Tags: airflow

Airflow version: 2.1.0

I set `FERNET_KEY` and checked `login/password` fields are encrypted when I add connections via Web UI.

However, when I add a connection via CLI:

```
airflow connections add 'site_account' \
    --conn-type 'login' \
    --conn-login 'my_user_id' \
    --conn-password 'wowpassword'
```

And run `airflow connections list`, it shows everything in raw value(not encrypted at all).

I think this could be dangerous enough if I manage all connections using CLI commands (I want to make my airflow infra restorable. That's why I tried to use CLI command to manage connections)

How to solve it?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you expect? Airflow needs to be able to decrypt the connection when DAG/user asks to. The security issue is about where the connections are stored and where the key to decrypt them is stored. If a malicious user already has access inside your app (Airflow) there is nothing Airflow can do about it. The security measurements are about storing the key securely and encrypting the database.

Comment: @Elad Thanks for the kind explanation! "If a malicious user already has access inside your app (Airflow) there is nothing Airflow can do about it" --> this is what I worried about and wanted to make clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow decrypts the connections passwords during the processing of your cli commands.
You can use `airflow connections list --o yaml` to see whether your record was actually encrypted in the database or not.

Furthermore, if you are able to access the cli, you are also able to access the config, meaning you can always extract the database connection and `fernet_key` and get the full password on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Jorrick answer is correct however I want to elaborate on the background as I feel it will bridge between the question and the answer.

It's very understandable that Airflow needs to be able to decrypt the connection when DAG/user asks to. This is needed for normal operation of the app so Airflow must assume that if a user can author DAGs he is permitted to utilize the system resources (Connections, Variables).

The security measurements are on a different level. If utilizing them (using [Fernet](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/secrets/fernet.html#fernet)) then Airflow will encrypt the sensitive information (like connection passwords) this means that in the database itself the value is encrypted. The security concern here is where the ferent_key is stored? is it rotating? etc...

There are many other security layers that handle different aspects like: access control, hiding sensitive information in the Ui but that's a different topic.

I think the important thing to understand that security handles two types of users:

1. A user that is permitted but you just want to limit what actions he can do or what he can see. (This is more what Airflow itself handles see security [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/index.html))
2. A user that is malicious and wants to do damage. While Airflow does provide some features in that area this is more of an issue of where you setup Airflow and how well you protect it (IP allow-list etc...)

keep in mind that if a malicious user gained access to Airflow server then there is little you can do about it. This user can simply use his admin privileges to do anything. This is no different than a user that hacked into any other server that you own.